# Animating using css on class change

Tags: javascript, css, class, animation

I am attempting to animate a property of the css for a form button using javascript by changing the class name. The property change is applied but is not animated and I cannot see why. Below is my code:

css:

```
button {
    padding-right: 0px;
    transition: padding-right 2.5s;

}

button.inactive {
    padding-right: 0px;

}

button.active {
    padding-right: 100px;
}
```

javascript(for transitioning to active):

```
this.form.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].className ="active";
```

(for transitioning to inactive):

```
this.form.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].className ="inactive";
```

Comment: The animations should be inside the .active and .inactive tags on your css part.

Comment: Do you mean the transition: line?

Answer (score 1):

I mocked up an example using your code that you provided and the animated transition is happening without a problem - can been seen here https://jsbin.com/qewolu/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: it's broken on Firefox for Mac, at least.

Answer (score 0):

```js
this.document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].addEventListener('click', function() {this.className ="active"});
```

```css
    a {
        padding: 10px;  
        border: 1px solid #39C;
        background-color: #036;
        color: white;
        transition: padding-right 2.5s;      
    }

    a.inactive {
        padding: 10px;
    }

    a.active {
        padding-right: 100px;
    }
```

```html
<a class="inactive">Test</a>
```

### Edit

Indeed @Rhi, his original code is working **partially on Chrome**. It seems the `button` element doesn't support padding transitions on Firefox. A possible workaround is to use anchor elements instead and style the `<A>` tag to look like a button. Please give a try on the snippet on this answer.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: Yes, i do not want to use jquery.

Comment: You don't have to. Just change the line `transition: padding-right 2.5s;` to `transition: padding 2.5s;` in your code, and check if it works. The code snippet is working.

Comment: It still does not animate with that change.

Comment: What browser and operating system are you using ? All answers to this question don't work on Firefox indeed.

Answer (score 0):

In this line,

```
this.form.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].className ="active";
```

How are you getting reference to form element?

I think you need to get reference of form element before accessing button.

Something like this will be better.

```
var form = document.myForm;
form.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].className ="active";
```

Demo https://jsfiddle.net/84133s8v/